# How do you call the operation of counting the number of euclidian division until the denominator is lower than the remainder?

Tags: operations-research

I was looking for the minimum size of a base35 secret_key to be able to generate at least 1,000,000 secret key.

The result is `35*35*35*35 = 1500625`

How do you call this operation of counting the number of euclidian division until the denominator is lower than the remainder ?

Comment: I think where you wrote "remainder" you mean "quotient" and where you write "quotient" you mean divisor. This is essentially an integer logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a special name, but in a formula this boils down to
$$\left\lceil\frac{\ln 1000000}{\ln 35}\right\rceil=4.$$

Comment: I love it thanks.

Comment: 35^x > 1000000 |
log_b(35^x) > log_b(1000000) |
x . log_b(35) > log_b(1000000) |
x > log_b(1000000) / log_b(35) |
x > 3.88...

Comment: So if we are 7 billions on the planet. If everybody knows 100 persons you can reach anybody in 5 hop. Great. Thank you for this demonstration.